# Place image in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with its respective adapter which is composed of a layout with an ImageView and some TextView, when I pass the data list I get the image that I must place as a URI in String, I don't know how to pass the String of the image to Uri for the ImageView:

```
public class AdapterProductos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProductos.ViewHolderProducto> {

    ArrayList<Producto> listProductos;

    public AdapterProductos(ArrayList<Producto> listProductos) {
        this.listProductos = listProductos;
    }

    //CONECTAR EL LAYOUT A EL ADAPTADOR
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderProducto onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_list_producto, null, false);
        return new ViewHolderProducto(view);
    }

    //OBTENER LOS DATOS
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderProducto holder, int position) {
        holder.nombre.setText(listProductos.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.descrip.setText(listProductos.get(position).getDescripcion());
        holder.valor.setText(listProductos.get(position).getValor());
        //holder.imagen.setImageURI(listProductos.get(position).getImagen());
    }

    //OBTENER EL TAMAÑO DE LA LISTA
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listProductos.size();
    }

    //ENLAZAR LOS ELEMENTOS VISUALES
    public class ViewHolderProducto extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView nombre, descrip, valor;
        ImageView imagen;
        public ViewHolderProducto(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen_itemProducto);
            nombre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_itemProducto);
            descrip = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descrip_itemProducto);
            valor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.valor_itemProducto);
        }
    }
}
```

**Editado:**
How can I implement the Uri.parse (image) in this part?:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderProducto holder, int position) {
    holder.nombre.setText(listProductos.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.descrip.setText(listProductos.get(position).getDescripcion());
    holder.valor.setText(listProductos.get(position).getValor());
}
```

Because to get the image I have to write:

```
holder.imagen.setImageURI (listProductos.get (position) .getImage ());
```

Comment: are you want to show the image using it's url?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to a URI converted to a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would recomend you to use Glide library[(link)](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).
It is a powerful tool for image loading that is also pretty easy to use.
To load the image as you want, you just need to write this:

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(url)
.into(imagen);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to add image URI use static method `Uri.parse("your image uri")`
when you want to add image URL you can use glide or picasso library in android
Picasso :

```
Picasso.get()
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

glide :

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(url)
.into(imagen);
```

Don't forget to add the library in dependency before use it.

From my experience I prefer glide it so fast and developed by google

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828' // Picasso library
```

this to add glide library

```
 repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }

   dependencies {
      implementation 'com.github.bumptech.`enter code here`glide:glide:4.11.0'
      annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    }
```